# how to add extra space before closing tag in bs4 prettify?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 to parse html output in my test suit and compare them with existing html files.
prettify and prettier behaviour seems different in how they manage closing tags.

Using the following inputs:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, formatter

fmt = formatter.HTMLFormatter(indent=2)
str_ = '<video preload="auto"><source src="_static/video.mkv" type=""/></video>'
html = BeautifulSoup(str_, "html.parser")
html.prettify(formatter=fmt)
```

I get the following output:

```html
<video preload="auto">
  <source src="_static/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

But to fully respect standards I should have an extra space before the closing tag (after the attributes of "source"). Is it possible ?

Comment: I think you forgot to add the output of the first code snippet?

Comment: I'm simply reusing the varaible in the second one, let me edit to clarify

Comment: If you pass `void_element_close_prefix=' /'` to *`.HTMLFormatter`* then the `source` tag should end with **`... />`** instead of *`.../>`* [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HQs5.png). Is that what you're going for?

Comment: that's exactly what I needed, if you publish it ass an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass `void_element_close_prefix=' /'` to `.HTMLFormatter` then the source tag should end with `... />` instead of `.../>`

```py
fmt = bs4.formatter.HTMLFormatter(indent=2, void_element_close_prefix=' /')
```

[image: op]